# Custom url in ionic framework

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I used this plugin for customURL scheme in my ionic project
 
`https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme` and my javascript code is

```
var handleOpenURL = function(url) {
    alert("RECEIVED URL: " + url);
    console.info(url);
      console.info(typeof(url));
      var a  = url.replace(/[A-Za-z$-.:/]/g, "");
      console.info(a);

};
```

I used `myapptest` as an url while installing the plugin 
but when i opened `myapptest:\\` in browser it is opening a web page instead of navigating to the app. 
Please suggest how to navigate to the app

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by:

```
var handleOpenURL = function(url) {
    alert("RECEIVED URL: " + url);
    var res = url.slice(12);
    console.log(res);
    window.location.href = "#/app/"+res;
};
```

Then tested it by calling handleOpenURL("myapptest:\search") inside the browser console.
It worked